# MySQL Join Query, unable to access first table id column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

MySQL Join Table with same id conflict:
Here is my query

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('manual');
$this->db->join('contact', 'contact.id = manual.contact_id');
$this->db->where('people_id',$practicien);
$this->db->where('DATE(day)', $datee);
$this->db->order_by('TIME(startTime)', 'ASC'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I need to access `id` column from `manual` table.
But when i use 'id' i'm getting the value of `id` column from `contact` table.

please fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select("manual.id as manual_id");
                $this->db->from('manual as manual');
                $this->db->join('contact as contact', 'contact.id = manual.contact_id');
                $this->db->where('people_id', $practicien);
                $this->db->where('DATE(day)', $datee);
                $this->db->order_by('TIME(startTime)', 'ASC');
                $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Alias Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html):

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t.id = t2.id
```

and then `t.id` or `t2.id` to access your id.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the table name before the field like that :

```
Select manual.id, * from ...
```

Comment: the query has to be implemented in codeigniter. so do i need to use $this->db->select('manual.id,*');

Comment: @Sparkz: Refer to: [*Codeigniter: Selecting Data*](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Answer (score 0):

add `or die (__LINE__." ".mysqli_error($con))` to see the error message

`$con` will be like this `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root")` ...

or use `or die (__LINE__." ".mysql_error())` to see the error message if U use mysql

Answer (score 0):

Using `*` has its problems.  One of the problems is when columns have the same name in different tables.

This might solve your problem:

```
select manual.id as manual_id, contact.*
. . .
```

If you need more columns from the `manual` table, just add them.  By using a column alias you remove the name collision problem.

As a note, SQL offers another mechanism for solving this problem when you use the `using` clause.  However, you can only do this when the foreign key reference and primary key have the same name.  This, in fact, is a good reason to use the same name for two columns that reference each other.  If you did this, your query could look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM manual m JOIN 
     contact c
     USING (contact_id)
WHERE people_id = '18' AND
      DATE(day) = '2014-03-13' 
ORDER BY TIME(startTime) ASC;
```

You wouldn't have the name conflict and you would only get one `id` column back.

Answer (score 0):

Since `manual.id` will be the 1st column in the array, you could do this -

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$row = $query->result_array();
return $row[0];
```

reference - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Or you can add it to your `select()` with an alias

```
$this->db->select('manual.id AS `yourid`, *', false);
```

reference - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: i tried the following line but getting a Internal server error.
$this->db->select('manual.id AS nid, *', FALSE);

Answer (score 0):

SKG answer helped me to achieve the output:
here is the final code.

```
$this->db->select('manual.id as rdvid, startTime, endTime, day, firstname, lastname');
$this->db->from('manual');
$this->db->join('contact', 'contact.id = manual.contact_id');
$this->db->where('people_id',$practicien);
$this->db->where('DATE(day)', $datee);
$this->db->order_by('TIME(startTime)', 'ASC'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
//print_r($this->db->last_query());
return $query;
```